# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'is' in SQL server vb6

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql

```
Set rs = con.Execute("select IIF(MAX(bill_bno) IS NULL,1,MAX(bill_bno)+1) from rec_all      where rw=0 and iif(month(bill_date)&gt;=1 AND month(bill_date)&lt;=3,year(bill_date)-1,year(bill_date))=" &amp; IIf(Month(Date) &gt;= 1 And Month(Date) &lt;= 3, Year(Date) - 1, Year(Date)))
```

how to change vb6 code (MS access) database to SQL Server 2012?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(bill_bno) + 1, 1) AS bill_bno
FROM   rec_all
WHERE  rw = 0
       AND 
       (CASE WHEN MONTH(bill_date) >= 1 AND MONTH(bill_date) <= 3
             THEN (YEAR(bill_date) - 1)
             ELSE YEAR(bill_date) END)
       =
       (CASE WHEN MONTH(Date) >= 1 AND MONTH(Date) <= 3
             THEN (YEAR(Date) - 1)
             ELSE YEAR(Date) END)
```

or this one:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(bill_bno) + 1, 1) AS bill_bno
FROM   rec_all
WHERE  rw = 0
       AND 
       (
       (MONTH(bill_date) >= 1 AND MONTH(bill_date) <= 3 AND (YEAR(bill_date) - 1) = (YEAR(Date) - 1))
       OR
       ((MONTH(bill_date) <> 1 OR MONTH(bill_date) <> 3) AND (YEAR(bill_date)) = (YEAR(Date)))
       )
```

Comment: Those `MONTH(..) = 1 AND MONTH(..) = 3` should be `MONTH(..) >= 1 AND MONTH(..) <= 3`

Answer (score 1):

Since you only gave us the line that generates your recordset, we'll assume that you are able to establish your connection successfully.

First: the following statement should be valid in SQL Server 2012:

```
select IIF(MAX(bill_bno) IS NULL,1,MAX(bill_bno)+1) from rec_all
 where rw=0
   and  iif(month(bill_date)>=1 AND month(bill_date)<=3,year(bill_date)-1,year(bill_date))
       =iif(Month(GETDATE())>= 1 And Month(GETDATE()) <= 3, Year(GETDATE()) - 1, Year(GETDATE()))
```

As far as I can tell, this is what you listed above, with the HTML-ification removed, and the SQL Server current date and time function `GETDATE()` replacing what I believe is the MS Access current date function `Date`.

I've displayed the query on multiple lines with indenting for human readability; you can put the full query on one line, if that's what you're language requires.

Not knowing the language you're using, I can't tell you how to properly format your actual con.execute command; change `>` and `<` to `&gt;` and `&lt;` if required.

As the other answers showed, there are other commands in SQL more commonly used to do the things you're doing (I had to check to be sure `iif` was available in T-SQL), but the major problem query-wise seems to have been how to get the current system date.

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
select max( isnull(billno, 0) ) + 1 from rec_all
```

Comment: I think your answer would benefit from some additional exposition.